# OpenMp Coding: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel

Tags: warnings, openmp

I am getting this warning during compilation of a C code with OpenMP directives on Linux:

```
warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
```

Gcc version is 4.4.

Is it only a warning I should not care about? Will the execution be in parallel?. I would like a solution with a some explanation.

I have provide `-fopenmp` with the `make` command, but gcc doesn't accept that, otherwise for single compilation of file, i.e. `gcc -fopenmp` works alright.

Answer (score 39):

IIRC you have to pass `-fopenmp` to the g++ call to actually enable OpenMP. This will also link against the OpenMP runtime system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that lib-gomp and lib-gomp-dev is installed. In some strange distributions it is removed. It is the essential runtime and development library.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a resolved/closed issue, because indeed the most common reason for this warning is the omission of the `-fopenmp` flag.

However, when I came across this problem the root cause for this was that the module `openmp` was not loaded, meaning:
`load module openmp`.